# hash-keys : contract violation in racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I have written the following function

```
(define (mk-initial-pagerank graph)
 (let* ((pages (remove-duplicates (apply append graph)))
     (num-pages (length pages)))
(let loop ((i 0) (pr '()))
  (if (= i num-pages)
      (reverse pr)
      (loop (+ i 1) (cons (cons (list-ref pages i) (/ 1 num-pages)) pr))))))
```

In this function when I try to display the function

```
(display(mk-initial-pagerank g0))
```

it gives me correct output as

```
((n2 . 1/5) (n0 . 1/5) (n1 . 1/5) (n4 . 1/5) (n3 . 1/5))
```

Now when I try to get those list as in proper manner I wrote the function as

```
(define (print-hash h)
(for ([k (sort (hash-keys h) symbol<?)])
(pretty-print `(,k ,(hash-ref h k)))))

  (print-hash (mk-initial-pagerank g0))
```

and my input is

```
(define g0 '((n2 n0)
         (n1 n4)
         (n4 n0)
         (n1 n3)
         (n2 n1)
         (n0 n1)
         (n3 n4)
         (n0 n4)
         (n4 n1)
         (n4 n2)
         (n1 n0)))
```

it gives me error as

```
hash-keys: contract violation
  expected: hash?
   given: '((n2 . 1/5) (n0 . 1/5) (n1 . 1/5) (n4 . 1/5) (n3 . 1/5))
```

here is my delete-duplicates function

```
(define (delete-duplicates lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
    ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) (delete-duplicates (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (delete-duplicates (cdr lst))))))
```

can anyone help to solve the error of hash-keys : contract violation ?

my desired output is

```
'(n0 1/5)
'(n1 1/5)
'(n2 1/5)
'(n3 1/5)
'(n4 1/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mk-initial-pagerank` function returns an [association list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) (*alist*), not a hash, so naturally `hash-keys` isn't going to work with it. There are interfaces like the [generic dictionary API](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html) that would accept them, but it's just as easy to sort the alist and use list iteration forms.

```lisp
(define (print-alist alist)
  (for ([elem (in-list (sort alist symbol<? #:key car))])
    (println (list (car elem) (cdr elem)))))

(print-alist '((n2 . 1/5) (n0 . 1/5) (n1 . 1/5) (n4 . 1/5) (n3 . 1/5)))
```

or maybe

```lisp
(define (print-alist alist)
  (for-each (lambda (elem) (println (list (car elem) (cdr elem))))
            (sort alist symbol<? #:key car)))
```

---

PS: Racket has [`remove-duplicates`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) in the `racket/list` module.